# access dropbox files from my app, download and upload files to dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

in my app i need the user to access to Dropbox, see the files (all the folders), being able to download and upload files like pictures and small sized audio file. i have tried the DBRoulette to understand the concept. got it to work also. the authentication is also fine. but i have no idea how to perform tasks like download/upload/ view all files.

i read about the "chooser" and "saver" also but i think i should use the "Core Api". please guide me on this.

any help to get me moving again will be appreciated guys.

thanks

Comment: I think you'll want to use the [Sync API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android). The [tutorial](https://stage.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android) and [documentation](https://stage.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android) should show you how to read and write files.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Dropbox for quite abit right now. I have no need to view a directory, but I am accessing files in multiple areas. If you already have your core Dropbox working, then you can write to any folder, will create if not there, with this.

```
// located in your dropboxHelper class
    public void writeToDropbox(File src) {
        String directory1 = "/TopFolder/";
        // Or for a sub folder
        String orThisDirectory = "/TopFolder/SubFolder/";
        myAsyncTask backup = new myAsyncTask(ctx, mDBApi, directory1, src);
        backup.execute();
    }
```

The filename will be the same as the file you are sending. If you need the Asynctask code, I can include that also. Just let me know.
To pull a file, I use this basic code.

```
public void restore(String fileGet, File fileSave, String sPath,
        String mFolder) {
    File file = new File(fileGet);
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileSave);
        otherAsyncTask restore = new otherAsyncTask (ctx, mDBApi,outputStream,
                file, sPath, mFolder);
        restore.execute();

    }
```

This will cover uploading and downloading. I only am using the Core API. And if you need the AsyncTask code also, Just ask. I figure you probably have that part though.

UPDATE
Get instance of your DropboxHelper. Put it in the class you are sending information from.

```
// Dropbox setup
    if (dropbox_option) {
        mDropbox = new DropboxHelper(ctx);
        if (!mDropbox.isLinked()) {
            mDropbox.completeAuthenticationDropbox();
        }
    }
```

In the Dropbox helper class, which I have all connection code and read-write methods.

```
public static DropboxHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mHelper == null) {
        mHelper = new DropboxHelper(context);
    }
    return mHelper;
}

public static DropboxHelper getInstance() throws Exception {
    if (mHelper == null)
        throw new Exception("DropboxHelper not yet instantiated");

    return mHelper;
}

public DropboxHelper(Context context) {
    super();
    ctx = context;

    // create session
    AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
    mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    if (isLinked()) {
        AccessKeys = getKeys();
        AccessTokenPair access = new AccessTokenPair(AccessKeys[0],
                AccessKeys[1]);
        mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(access);
    } else {
        mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(ctx);
    }
}

private String[] getKeys() {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    String key = prefs.getString(Global.DROPBOX_ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
    String secret = prefs
            .getString(Global.DROPBOX_ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
    if (key != null && secret != null) {
        String[] ret = new String[2];
        ret[0] = key;
        ret[1] = secret;
        return ret;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}


 // Clear token 

public void clearKeysToken() {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.clear();
    edit.commit();
}

protected void storeKeys(String key, String secret) {
    // prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putString(Global.DROPBOX_ACCESS_KEY_NAME, key);
    edit.putString(Global.DROPBOX_ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, secret);
    edit.commit();
}
       // Create a session

private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
    AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(Global.APP_KEY,
            Global.APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session;
    String[] stored = getKeys();
    if (stored != null) {
        AccessTokenPair accessToken = new AccessTokenPair(stored[0],
                stored[1]);
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair,
                Global.DROPBOX_ACCESS_TYPE, accessToken);
    } else {
        session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair,
                Global.DROPBOX_ACCESS_TYPE);
    }

    return session;
}

// Complete authentication

public void completeAuthenticationDropbox() {
    session = mDBApi.getSession();
    // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
    // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
    // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
    if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // complete authentication
            session.finishAuthentication();
            // save login credentials
            TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
            storeKeys(tokens.key, tokens.secret);
            // setLoggedIn(true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx,
                    "Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:" + e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
        } finally {
            if (isLinked()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "dropbox is linked");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Dropbox is NOT linked.");
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "WTF");
    }
}

// Returns true if you are connected to Dropbox
public boolean isLinked() {
    return mDBApi.getSession().isLinked();

}
public void logIn() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Login");
    mDBApi.getSession().startAuthentication(ctx);
}
```

Learn how to get this working from sifting through [this code](https://code.google.com/p/android-money-manager-ex/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fdropbox2%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fmoney%2Fmanager%2Fex%2Fdropbox).

Comment: thank you so much. my knowledge in dropbox activities is very limited to the example app DBRoulette only. what this app does is it accesses dropbox and opens a random jpeg file. in the other hand i need to see files, upload and download to dropbox.

can you guide me abit further more. for example how to implement the method you just provided.

and no i dun need the sync part